# flex property messes with button height?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm using bootstrap and making a layout with flex.

Currently the button is taking the height of the container. There is an awful lot of space under the text and i want to remove i and when I add padding to the button its becomes uneven in size. I tried to adjust the size by line height but i trying to find the actual solution and the reason as to why i'm having this problem.

Anything that i'm missing here with flex or is it something else?
Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

```css
.vessel-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.vessel-card h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.departure-card {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #888;
}
.departure-card p {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.departure-card:last-child {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #888;
}
.departure-card .btn-explore {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 vessel-card">
      <a href="cienfuegos-from-havana.html" class="special-departure">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </a>
      <h3>Vessel: Panorama</h3>
      <div class="departure-card">
        <p>Havana to Cienfuegos starting at $5,999</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-explore">Explore</a>
      </div>
      <div class="departure-card">
        <p>Havana to Cienfuegos starting at $5,999</p>
        <a href="cienfuegos-from-havana.html" class="btn btn-explore">Explore</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Flexbox** make items same `height` as you can see here [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/6qym530t/) , but you can use [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) to change that or in your case [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/6qym530t/1/)

```css
.parent {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.child:first-child {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Just to add,  you have default `margin` on `p` tag and also you can use other `align-items` options like `flex-start` https://jsfiddle.net/6qym530t/2/

Comment: what does flex-start does?

Comment: Its like `vertical-align: top` for flex items but the difference is it actually works `:)`

Comment: Use `align-items: start` to align vertical at top.

Answer (score 10):

#### There are two possible solutions

**1.** `d-flex` with `align-items-*` can help you.

```html
<link
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-info" style="height: 160px;">
  <button class="btn btn-success">align-items-* saved me :)</button>
</div>
```

**2.** No `css` required, just wrap the `button` with `span` or `div`

```html
<link
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-around bg-info" style="height: 160px;">
  <span>
    <button class="btn btn-success">span or div saved me :)</button>
  </span>
 
  <button class="btn btn-danger">Aw, flex infected me ;(</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler solution. This solution aligns the button to the center horizontally and does not mess with the height of the button or other child elements.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the button in the paragraph.  I've also included a `padding` to the button of `5px` so that the box isn't so close to the text, but the value can be changed to suit your needs, or removed entirely if undesired.

```css
.vessel-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.vessel-card h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.departure-card {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #888;
}
.departure-card p {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.departure-card:last-child {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #888;
}
.departure-card .btn-explore {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 vessel-card">
      <a href="cienfuegos-from-havana.html" class="special-departure">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </a>
      <h3>Vessel: Panorama</h3>
      <div class="departure-card">
        <p>Havana to Cienfuegos starting at $5,999
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-explore">Explore</p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="departure-card">
        <p>Havana to Cienfuegos starting at $5,999
          <a href="cienfuegos-from-havana.html" class="btn btn-explore">Explore</p></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

on Bootstrap
other align-items values for https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#align-items
and other justify-content values for https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content

```
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
   <button>Save</button>
 </div>
```